# C++ Constructor Question

Tags: c++

If I create a default parameter in my ctor then how will the compiler know which ctor to call the default ctor or the ctor with a default parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't.  If you have the following class:

```
struct S {
    S();
    S(int = 0);
};
```

Then the compiler will report that the following is ambiguous:

```
S x;
```